# Google Maps Android Api Geocoder quotas

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

If I am using the android google maps api and inside my code I use the geocoder class such as this:

```
geocoder.getFromLocation(
                location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude(),
                // In this sample, get just a single address.
                1);
```

am I using the android api or am I using the geocoder api? I ask because the android api seems to have unlimited quotas while the geocoding api has a quota? So if I make reverse geocoding calls say from an android device am I limited?

Comment: If you are using the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html the important statement is `The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework.` So while the framework Geocoder may seem unlimited - it may not exist..

Comment: @MorrisonChang So just to confirm, it is using the geocding api and thus limited to the quotas specified by the api?